# react-native iOS signature export ipa file error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. xcode9,error log:

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9

xcode9 sign ,export ipa file error:The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format,The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format,why?
error logs:
IDEDistribution.standard.log:

```
2018-02-09 01:53:02 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: wepilotrelase, task: Export
    2018-02-09 01:53:04 +0000 [MT] Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionAnalyzeArchiveStepViewController, context: <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb2d7de0; archive(resolved)='<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionTask(resolved)='2', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team(resolved)='(null)'>
        Chain (3, self inclusive):
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb2d7de0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='(null)'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fcd12fe94f0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='(null)'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb62e080; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='(null)', team='(null)'>
    </IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb2d7de0>
    2018-02-09 01:53:04 +0000  Found team <IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fcd15aec320: teamID: 7PEH5UAQ6Q, teamName: Wepilot Inc.> in archive signature
    2018-02-09 01:53:04 +0000  Found signing style 0 in archive signature
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000 [MT] Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionOptionsStepViewController, context: <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fcd15bd7350; archive(resolved)='<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionTask(resolved)='2', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team(resolved)='<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fcd15aec320: teamID: 7PEH5UAQ6Q, teamName: Wepilot Inc.>'>
        Chain (5, self inclusive):
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fcd15bd7350; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fcd15aec320: teamID: 7PEH5UAQ6Q, teamName: Wepilot Inc.>'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfca3ec70; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fcd15aec320: teamID: 7PEH5UAQ6Q, teamName: Wepilot Inc.>'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb2d7de0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fcd15aec320: teamID: 7PEH5UAQ6Q, teamName: Wepilot Inc.>'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fcd12fe94f0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7fcd0c7aa3a0>', team='(null)'>
        <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fccfb62e080; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fcd15b15e90>', distributionMethod='(null)', team='(null)'>
    </IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fcd15bd7350>
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool '/var/folders/05/q44hlzbx3c917jnb4dsj2lh00000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.RIE' '--json' '/var/folders/05/q44hlzbx3c917jnb4dsj2lh00000gn/T/ipatool-json-filepath-HjI4QV' '--info' '--toolchain' '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr' '--platforms' '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms'
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1593: warning: assigned but unused variable - minVersion
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1593: warning: assigned but unused variable - sdkVersion
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1602: warning: assigned but unused variable - sourceVersion
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1703: warning: shadowing outer local variable - node
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2470: warning: shadowing outer local variable - machoFile
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2470: warning: shadowing outer local variable - machoImage
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2497: warning: key :hasBitcode is duplicated and overwritten on line 2499
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2662: warning: assigned but unused variable - flag
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2662: warning: assigned but unused variable - transformer
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2912: warning: assigned but unused variable - exc
    2018-02-09 01:53:06 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:738: warning: assigned but unused variable - output
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  : cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:24:in `<main>'
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  

    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1
    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  

    2018-02-09 01:53:07 +0000  ipatool JSON: (null)
    2018-02-09 01:55:20 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Comment: are you able to run app in device ?,

Comment: I'm having similar problem, still unable to solve it

Comment: In my case, restart XCode solved the problem.
Not sure it is related though, I'm using rvm and execute `rvm use system`  before restart XCode.

Answer (score 10):

Had exact same issue. Satoshi's comment worked for me.

- Quit Xcode
- Open terminal and run `rvm use system`
- Reopen Xcode and build

Comment: I tried this and it somehow removed my Cocoapods and so I started getting other errors. I am also on Xcode 10.1

Comment: If using chruby, `chruby system` will do the trick as well.